# Determine whether $a_n$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n = \frac{2n}{3n+1}$

(a) Determine whether $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

(b) Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent.

I am having trouble getting started with (a). Is the question asking to find the limit of $a_n$? If so that would be $\frac{2}{3}$ I believe.

Then for (b), I am trying to convert this into a geometric series, but I haven't been able to figure out how to. I observe that

$\begin{align}
a_1 = \frac{2}{4}, a_2 = \frac{4}{7}, a_3 = \frac{6}{10}
\end{align}$

but I don't see a pattern.

Comment: for a, you could prove that 2/3 is the limit using the definition

Comment: For (b), recall that the series $\sum a_n$ cannot converge unless the sequence $a_n$ converges to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the limit of the sequence $a_n=\frac{2n}{3n+1}$.

We have indeed that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\frac23$

There are several ways to show this. If you know about limit theorems, you can use them like this:

It is $\frac{2n}{3n+1}=\frac{2}{3+\frac1n}$. Now the numerator coverges obviously against $2$ and the denominator converges against $3$. So the fraction converges against $\frac23$.

An other would be straight by definition:

$\forall\varepsilon >0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ sucht that for every $n\geq N$ holds that $|a_n-\frac23|<\varepsilon$.

'Sketch':

Let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary. We have to find $N$.

It is $|a_n-\frac23|=|\frac{2n}{3n+1}-\frac23|=|\frac{6n-6n-2}{3(3n+1)}|=\frac{2}{3(3n+1)}<\frac{1}{3n+1}<\frac1n<\frac1N$.

If we choose $N=\lceil \frac1\varepsilon\rceil$ we could conclude the proof.

For b):

As mentioned in the comments a series can only converge if you take the sum over a null sequence.
If the sequence is not a null sequence, the series can not converge.

However if you have a null sequence it is not sure that the series converges also.
The standard counterexample is:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$

the harmonic series, which does not converge!